# How to Center a BoxView relative to another BoxView using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am an iOS Developer, learning Xamarin Forms.

I am trying to center a `BoxView` relative to another `BoxView`. Both the boxes are like siblings, added over a `RelativeLayout`. And the second box has half the width and half the height of the first box. How do I achieve that?

Right now, I can make the second box half of the first box by adding `HeighConstraint` and `WidthConstraint` with `Factor`. But I am not sure how to center both the views. In iOS, I can easily do that by adding just two constraints - center to X and center to Y. But I don't find anything like that in Xamarin Forms.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="PhoneWord.ExplorePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <BoxView
                x:Name="GrayBox"
                Color="Gray"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.4}"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}">
            </BoxView>
            <BoxView
                BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=GrayBox, Property=X, Constant=100}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=GrayBox, Property=Y, Constant=50}"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=GrayBox, Property=Height, Factor=0.5}"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=GrayBox, Property=Width, Factor=0.5}">
            </BoxView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. I have to use the `Factor` with the `Property X` for `XConstraint`.

Since my height is 0.5 of the first box, I have to use 0.25 factor ((1-0.5)/2). If I increased the height to 0.75, I have to use facor 0.125 ((1-0.75)/2)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="PhoneWord.ExplorePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <BoxView
                x:Name="GrayBox"
                Color="Gray"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.4}"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}">
            </BoxView>
            <BoxView
                BackgroundColor="Red"
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=GrayBox, Property=Width, Factor=0.25}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=GrayBox, Property=Height, Factor=0.25}"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=GrayBox, Property=Height, Factor=0.5}"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=GrayBox, Property=Width, Factor=0.5}">
            </BoxView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```